# Custom name server removes the ability of visiting websites with 'dev' in the url

Tags: dns

I am a web developer and in my younger years I tried setting up a custom name server on my mac without really knowing what I was doing. I wanted to be able to visit my own website on adreses like 'sam.dev'.

I know that I succeeded at some point and threw the program, that helped me set it up, from my macbook because it was just a trial version.

Now, a couple of years later I notice that I cannot go to any website that has .dev or dev. in the url.

This means I cannot visit websites like nodejs.dev or web.dev

I have tried resetting my DNS but I can't get it to work again.
How would I go about resetting this and what did I do wrong?

more info:

```
scutil --dns significant return values:

resolver #8
  domain   : test
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  port     : 20560
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #9
  domain   : dev
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  port     : 20560
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)
```

contents of etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# BEGIN section for OpenVPN Client SSL sites
127.94.0.1  client.openvpn.net
# END section for OpenVPN Client SSL sites
```

I fixed my problem for .dev domains like web.dev but I still have the problem for sites like dev.to

Comment: Do you still now the name of the application you used to set it up? How did you try to reset DNS? Which name servers are listed in your system preferences? Can you add the content of `/etc/hosts` and the output of `scutil --dns` to the question?

Comment: I used Namo (mamp.info/namo).

Answer (score 1):

I have been passively looking for this for over a year now.
thanks to @nohillside I found that the `.dev` redirect were resolvers and looked into my `/etc/` and found a folder called `resolver`.

(get to `/etc/resolver/` on mac using `CMD-SHIFT-G` in finder)

This folder contained the file named `dev` with the contents:

```
# Lovingly generated by Pow
nameserver 127.0.0.1
port 20560
```

from the [pow website](https://pow.cx):

> And Pow eliminates the need to edit /etc/hosts.

I am now wondering if I used some other application that used Pow internally and didn't clean up after itself.

Comment: Great! You probably can use `lsof` to figure out which process is listening on 20560.